# Access to an array position with an static variable in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, static

I am trying to assign an object to an array position. The position is given by an static variable (int) that contains the number of elements of the array. The size of tEntities is 5 and the size of fFuncionesList is 4, so it´s not a size problem.

```
if (TEntity::uEntityCount < 5)
        {
            iRandFuncList = rand() % (3 + 1);
            iRandPosX = rand() % (120 + 1);
            iRandPosY = rand() % (30 + 1);
            tEntities[TEntity::uEntityCount] = new TEntity((fFuncionesList[iRandFuncList]), iRandPosX, iRandPosY);
        }

TEntity(funcEntity *funcs, int x, int y)
    {
        m_ix = x;
        m_iy = y;
        m_funcs = funcs;
        uEntityCount++;
    }
```

[image: Error]
[image: Debuger]

I have tried to assign the value of the static variable to an int variable and it works, I would like to understand why it doesn't work with the static variable.

```
if (TEntity::uEntityCount < 5)
            {
                iRandFuncList = rand() % (3 + 1);
                iRandPosX = rand() % (120 + 1);
                iRandPosY = rand() % (30 + 1);
                int pos = TEntity::uEntityCount;
                tEntities[pos] = new TEntity((fFuncionesList[iRandFuncList]), iRandPosX, iRandPosY);
            }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the size of `fFuncionesList`?

Comment: @goodvibration 4

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get a compilation error, a runtime error of a weird output?

Comment: `I have tried to assign the value of the static variable to an int variable and it works, I would like to understand why it doesn't work with the static variable. ` - implies that your program's behavior is undefined, and adding another variable on the stak has changed its behavior (and coincidentally made it do what you wanted).

Comment: @רועי אבידן Access violation reading location, the array position is empty

Comment: Steps for you to investigate your problem: 1. You've given a flow which fails and a flow which works, but both flows are calling `rand`. How do you know for a fact that this behavior is consistent??? Get rid of those `rand` calls, and make sure that this behavior is indeed consistent. 2. Find out constant values which yield the failure that you've mentioned. Post your `TEntity` constructor; For all we know, the problem could be there, when it tries to execute the function that you're passing it. In short, do some minimal debugging work here.

Comment: I have added the constructor to the question and tried without rand(), I still get the same result.

Comment: 1) Why `rand() % (3 + 1)` instead of, simply, `rand() % 4`? It is essentially the same thing. 2) Please provide [mre].

Comment: sounds like `tEntities` is not a valid pointer. But you should post a Minimal, Reproducible Example. And stop using raw pointers

Comment: If `tEntities` is size 4, then do the math. Look at the picture you posted. Which slot are you indexing? Hint: `tEntities[4]` is the **fifth** element. Regardless, without a [mcve] its all guesswork anyway. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes when you call constructor

```
tEntities[TEntity::uEntityCount] = new TEntity((fFuncionesList[iRandFuncList]),...);
```

it increment the  uEntityCount

```
uEntityCount++;
```

then you assign the object pointer to tEntities[TEntity::uEntityCount] it will be placed at the next position so if current uEntityCount=4 it will place the pointer at uEntityCount=5 which is outside you array